# How to call a File pointer in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function-calls

I need to scan a file for letters to form a scrambled word. Everything looks okay but the debugger doesnt execute the command. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
void playGame(char array1[SIZE], FILE*aPtr)    
{

    aPtr = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        fscanf(aPtr, " %c", array1[i]);
        printf("%c", array1[i]);
    }
}
```

**Heres how I call the function in main**

```
playGame(&scramble[SIZE], inPtr);
```

the array scramble[] is declared as is the FILE*inPtr, Also, SIZE is defined as 10.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  But If you are opening the FILE *inside* your function, then you don't need to send it in as a parameter.

Comment: What precisely are you trying to do, and what is your error message? What do you mean, 'the debugger doesn't execute the command'? Usually, `C` code is compiled, linked, loaded by the operating system and run by the CPU -- no debuggers involved.

Comment: It says "Assignment3.exe has stopped working". And I ran it with the debugger but it wouldnt even debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your calling code, you have:

```
FILE *fp = 0;
char game[SIZE];
```

Given that you're opening the file in the function, but not closing it, you need to change the file in the function, so the call could be:

```
playGame(game, &fp);
if (fp != 0)
    fclose(fp);
```

But the function should be changed to:

```
void playGame(char array1[SIZE], FILE **aPtr)    
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        *aPtr = fp;
        ...other code...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the file should be opened and closed in the calling code and the file pointer simply passed to `playGame()`:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
if (fp != 0)
{
    playGame(game, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

With this interface, there is no `fopen()` (or `fclose()`) call in `playGame()`, which keeps its current interface (`void playGame(char game[SIZE], FILE *fp)`).  This makes more sense.  Very often it is correct for the function that opens a file to be responsible for closing it too.  There are exceptions, but not all that many of them.